# How to get from phy_device to net_device?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm trying to implement phy statistics reading by ethtool from a custom switch driver.
Ethtool doesn't see the phy_driver structure I declared in my driver, because it simply has an empty dev->phydev pointer in function __ethtool_get_sset_count.
I have a phydev pointer returned from MDIO bus scan, retrieved by:

```
mv_switch->phydev = (struct phy_device *)mv_switch->mii_bus->mdio_map[mv_switch->mdio_addr]
```

but can't understand how to get to the parent net_device pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[struct phy_device](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/phy.h#L359) has a field called `attached_dev` for that purpose, I guess... Proof [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/phy.h#L434).

So one could assume that the following would work for your use case

```
struct net_device *dev = mv_switch->phydev->attached_dev;
```

Comment: Thank you Justin, I've already tried that, unfortunately, attached_dev resulted NULL in my case, I guess no-one is initializing it. I'm now investigating function phy_attach_direct.

Comment: Interesting. It means that your code happens before `phy_attach_direct` is being called (if it is called at all). This link (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/phy_attach_direct) shows where this function is used, maybe that'll help you